# Does the Jordan form of the matrix depend on where the Jordan blocks are placed?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let's say that we have the matrix \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 4 &  -1 \\
-4  & 13  &   -3 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Now, the characteristic polynomial denoted by $C_p(A)= \lambda(\lambda-1)^2$ implies that there will be one jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$. Hence all that is left to find are the number of jordan blocks for $\lambda=1$. After row reducing it is clear that the eigenspace for $\lambda=1$ is one dimensional and so it must be a jordan block of size $2$.

So here is my question. Does the order of the Jordan blocks matter? That is, are $J_2(1)\oplus J_1(0)$ and $J_1(0)\oplus J_2(1) $ equivalent expressions? Or is there some order that must be adhered to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No there is no specific order required, just as if you diagonalize a matrix, there is no real reason to pick one ordering of eigenvalues over another.

Comment: Jordan normal form is only defined up to reordering. Also, you can conjugate your block-diagonal matrix by a permutation matrix to permute the blocks arbitrarily.

Comment: The Jordan canonical form (when it exists) is unique up to permutation of the blocks, so any order you pick is up to you. As a comparison, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic roughly says every there is a unique prime factorization (unique up to ordering of the factors). So, for example, $40 = 2^3 \times 5 = 2\times 5 \times 2^2 = 5 \times 2^3$. Would you really care which order it is presented in?

Comment: @peek-a-boo That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: In some countries the Jordan form is taught with the extra 1's below the main diagonal. This is fine; the fact that the two ways are visibly "similar" is one proof that any matrix is similar to its transpose.

Answer (score 2):

The order does not matter. Any twoJordan forms of a matrix are similar and different order of blocks gives a
smilar Jordan form.